# SQL coding error

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am running the below query:-

```
SELECT 
  FISCALYEAR, 
  DATENAME(Month,JVDate) as Month,
  ACCOUNTNUMBER,
  ACCOUNTDESCRIPTION, 
  CATEGORY, 
  POSTINGTYPE,
  sum(ORIGNETAMOUNT) as ORIGNETAMOUNT
FROM dbo.vw_GLTrialBalancev2010 
INNER JOIN GL00100 
        ON GL00100.ACTNUMBR_1 = dbo.vw_GLTrialBalancev2010.SEGMENT1 
        AND GL00100.ACTNUMBR_2 = dbo.vw_GLTrialBalancev2010.SEGMENT2
group by FISCALYEAR, 
  DATENAME(Month,JVDate) as Month,
  ACCOUNTNUMBER,
  ACCOUNTDESCRIPTION, 
  CATEGORY, 
  POSTINGTYPE,
  sum(ORIGNETAMOUNT) as ORIGNETAMOUNT
```

But getting the following error:-

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'as'.

It must have been a long day today because for the life of me I cannot see what is wrong with it???

Can someone else spot it????

Comment: as 'Month'; it should be in quotes, I believe

Comment: Why do you want to group by the sum? In my answer earlier to your question there isn't that in the group by.

Comment: okay sorted it.  I took out the sum and then also had to take out the 'as Month' from the grouping.  all help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as` is not allowed in `group by` clauses.  Try this:

```
SELECT 
  FISCALYEAR, 
  DATENAME(Month,JVDate) as Month,
  ACCOUNTNUMBER,
  ACCOUNTDESCRIPTION, 
  CATEGORY, 
  POSTINGTYPE,
  sum(ORIGNETAMOUNT) as ORIGNETAMOUNT
FROM dbo.vw_GLTrialBalancev2010 
INNER JOIN GL00100 
        ON GL00100.ACTNUMBR_1 = dbo.vw_GLTrialBalancev2010.SEGMENT1 
        AND GL00100.ACTNUMBR_2 = dbo.vw_GLTrialBalancev2010.SEGMENT2
group by FISCALYEAR, 
  DATENAME(Month,JVDate),
  ACCOUNTNUMBER,
  ACCOUNTDESCRIPTION, 
  CATEGORY, 
  POSTINGTYPE,
  sum(ORIGNETAMOUNT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to take out the 'sum' and 'as Month' from grouping.

see below:-

```
SELECT 
  FISCALYEAR, 
  DATENAME(Month,JVDate) as Month,
  ACCOUNTNUMBER,
  ACCOUNTDESCRIPTION, 
  CATEGORY, 
  POSTINGTYPE,
  sum(ORIGNETAMOUNT) as ORIGNETAMOUNT 
FROM dbo.vw_GLTrialBalancev2010 
INNER JOIN GL00100 
        ON GL00100.ACTNUMBR_1 = dbo.vw_GLTrialBalancev2010.SEGMENT1 
        AND GL00100.ACTNUMBR_2 = dbo.vw_GLTrialBalancev2010.SEGMENT2
group by FISCALYEAR, DATENAME(Month,JVDate), ACCOUNTNUMBER, 
         ACCOUNTDESCRIPTION, CATEGORY, POSTINGTYPE
```